# PagingDataAdapter.refresh() not working after fragment navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-paging-3

I am using `PagingDataAdapter` in one fragment to show user activity.
in fragment class level,

```
private var activityAdapter: ActivityFeedAdapter? = null
```

in `onCreate()` I am initializing before use as,

```
activityAdapter = initAdapter()
```

also in `onCreate()`,

```
this.lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
        viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
             viewModel.getActivityFeed().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                 it?.let {
                     activityAdapter?.submitData(lifecycle, it)
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

and after `onStart()`, I am setting a click Listener on a view to refresh `pagingdata` from the UI as,

```
binding?.refresh?.setOnClickListener {
            activityAdapter?.refresh()
        }
```

Everything works fine when I use it for the first load. But after I navigate to some fragment and get back to the same screen, clicking on refresh only handles click event but does not refresh the adapter.

BTW, I have initialized the adapter in `onCreate()` because I need the adapter to maintain loaded data across screen transitions. Anyone help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the bug... :))

In `onCreate()` I was setting observer with lifecycleOwner as `viewLifecycleOwner`.

But `viewLifecycleOwner` is only active from `onCreateView()` till `onDestroyView()`. So after navigation to a different fragment and getting back from there, the new observer was not set. The old observer is canceled due to lifecycleOwner is destroyed. So I could refresh more data in `PagingDataAdapter`.

When setting the observer please rethink which lifecycleOwner is to be used. Hope this might help someone. :)